# pass jquery variable into function oncomplete

Tags: jquery, salesforce, visualforce

I have a commandButton in a visualforce page that I need to add the oncomplete attribute.

```
<apex:commandButton id="btnParticipant" value="Add Participant" action="{!addParticipant}" reRender="participantTable" />
```

I need to call a jquery method I've defined and pass in the table rows as my argument.  Here is my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    j$(document).ready(function() {
        var dataRows = j$('tr.dataRow');

        dataRows.each(function(index, elem) {
            updateImages(elem);
        });

        j$("img[id$=':deleteImage']").on("click", function(event) {
            updateImages(j$(this).closest('tr'));
        });

        j$('[id$=btnParticipant]').on("click", function(event){
            var dataRows = j$('tr.dataRow');
            dataRows.each(function(index, elem) {
                updateImages(elem);
            });
        });

    });

    function updateImages(myRow) {  
        var rowInputs =  j$(myRow).find('input[type="text"]');
        var contact = (j$(rowInputs[0]).val()); 
        var user = (j$(rowInputs[1]).val());
        var account = (j$(rowInputs[2]).val());

        if (contact !== '') {
            j$(rowInputs[0].parentNode).find('img').show();
            j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode).find('img').hide();
            j$(rowInputs[2].parentNode).find('img').hide();
        }    
        else if (user !== '') {
            j$(rowInputs[0].parentNode).find('img').hide();
            j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode).find('img').show();
            j$(rowInputs[2].parentNode).find('img').hide();
        }
        else if (account !== '') {
            j$(rowInputs[0].parentNode).find('img').hide();
            j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode).find('img').hide();
            j$(rowInputs[2].parentNode).find('img').show();
        }
        if (account !== '' && contact !== '') {
            j$(rowInputs[0].parentNode).find('img').show();
            j$(rowInputs[1].parentNode).find('img').hide();
            j$(rowInputs[2].parentNode).find('img').hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

In particular, I need to somehow duplicate this portion of the code with the oncomplete attribute:

```
var dataRows = j$('tr.dataRow');

        dataRows.each(function(index, elem) {
            updateImages(elem);
        });
```

Basically, the above code takes each table row with the class name "datacell" and loops over the rows and hides certain images.

How can I call this code using the oncomplete attribute in the commandButton?

Thanks for any help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question. If I understood correctly it should be something like

```
    <apex:commandButton id="btnParticipant" value="Add Participant"
 action="{!addParticipant}" reRender="participantTable" oncomplete="updateRows()"/>

j$(document).ready(function() {
   updateRows();     
});

function updateRows(){
       var dataRows = j$('tr.dataRow');

        dataRows.each(function(index, elem) {
            updateImages(elem);
        });

        j$("img[id$=':deleteImage']").on("click", function(event) {
            updateImages(j$(this).closest('tr'));
        });

        j$('[id$=btnParticipant]').on("click", function(event){
            var dataRows = j$('tr.dataRow');
            dataRows.each(function(index, elem) {
                updateImages(elem);
            });
        });
}
```